# How do you unit test a task that cannot be run with CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True?

Tags: unit-testing, celery

In my django project, I have some celery tasks that are supposed to be executed after a certain time (when in testing mode, the waiting time is set to just a few seconds). After execution of these tasks, they will change some states of entities. I have written tests to check those states immediately after the tasks are scheduled.

I tried to use `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` to test celery tasks in my django unit testing. However, with that setting, it waits for the tasks to be executed locally and results returned. So my previous testing code breaks because of this.

Let me give a more specific example. Say I have an order system for an eCommerce platform. When buyers make an order, a celery task is created to check if the order is paid successfully within 24 hours. If not paid, then the order should be cancelled. When in testing mode, I can make the countdown to be 20s instead of 24 hours. But with django unit testing, if I use CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True, then this celery task is executed immediately so the order will always be cancelled. How can I test the case that the payment is made successfully within the time limit (20s)?

Does anyone know how you can test celery tasks that just cannot be executed immediately?

Comment: Testing periodic celery task is not a problem, generally speaking. Add a [mcve] to your question so that we can see what your *actual* problem is.

Comment: Thanks Louis! Sorry I have to make one correction about the question: it is not about periodic tasks, but about tasks that are supposed to be executed some time later (with countdown or ETA).

Comment: So one example case: say I have an order system for an ecommerce platform. When buyers made an order, a celery task is created to check if the order is paid successfully if the order is paid successfully within 24 hours. If not paid, then the order should be cancelled. When in testing mode, I can make the countdown to be 20s instead of 24 hours. But with django unit testing, if I use CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True, then this celery task is executed immediately so the order will always be cancelled. How can I test the case that the payment is made successfully within the time limit (20s)?

Comment: Ok, edit your question with the information you've given. I still think a [mcve] would help get good answers. In a situation like the one you have, the devil is in the details, and it is easy to get the details wrong when answering.

Comment: One solution I can think of is to let the django unit test start celery, and make celery connect to the test database used in django testing.

Comment: I've done that in one of my project but the issue was different (had nothing to do countdowns).

Comment: Create two orders.  Set one creation_date -25 hours, set one creation date -23 hours.  Run the task with ALWAYS_EAGER.  Ensure that the first order was cancelled and the second was not. 

This is an important technique for time-based testing.  Keep it in your toolbelt.